# Incorporate offset into mgcv GAM smoothing

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, offset

When developing mortality models, I often have the following problem: I have a prior/base rate table and mortality experience data from a population of interest, and I need to develop factors on top of the base table that adjust it to give a best fit to the dataset. This problem can be solved using a binomial GAM with logit link and the following formula:

```
q_a ~ offset(logit(q_e)) + s(x, y)
```

where $q_a$ is the empirical mortality rate in the data, $q_e$ is the rate expected from the base table, and $x$ and $y$ are predictors in the experience dataset. This gives me a model $f(x,y)$ such that $q^*(x,y) = \text{logit}^{-1} [f(x,y) + \text{logit}(q_e)]$ is the desired adjusted mortality.

This approach works splendidly for the most part, but has one aspect that isn't ideal: mgcv is smoothing the adjustment term $f(x,y)$, but what I want it to smooth is the (logit of) the final rates, $\text{logit}\, q^*(x,y) = f(x,y) + \text{logit}(q_e)$. In other words, I want the second-difference smoothing penalty to be applied to $f(x,y) + \text{logit}(q_e)$  rather than just $f(x,y)$. Is there any way to make mgcv do that? It looks like "linear functional terms" might be helpful here, but the mgcv documentation isn't 100% clear on how they are treated in the smoothing penalty.

Comment: How is smoothing of $f(x,y) + \text{logit}(q_e)$ different from smoothing $f(x,y)$?